# pronunciation for consecutive /d/ and /ð/

Tags: pronunciation

> Mr. Barnett has slamm**ed the** figure as outrageous. [(Aussie ABC News)](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/150)

/d/ and /ð/ are made at different places, we don’t drop any one of them when pronouncing, like the news anchor, do we?

Comment: Did the news anchor drop one? I can't tell from your wording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, certainly.  The /d/ assimilates and is no more in all of these:

- Sound the  alarm!
- Jimmy and the other boys.
- They banned the rioters.
- Don’t brand that horse.
- A friend that’s easy to talk to.
- I found this one early.
- I didn’t intend that effect.
- The land that we love.
- It’s in the pond that your father dug out.
- Please refund this woman her money.
- I second that idea.
- He turned the other cheek.
- The wind that blows loudest bites hardest.

As evidence, consider those few words with a “ndth” sequence in them: none of them have an audible /d/:

- spendthrift
- thousandth

Comment: Thank you. I had got the memory of your answer; yet after hearing her pronunciation, I got confused.

Comment: This is because it's almost impossible to move from pronouncing a nasal dental stop [n] to pronouncing an interdental fricative [ð] without pronouncing an oral dental stop [d] in between. Two things have to happen to two different articulators: (a) the velic flap has to shut off the nasal release to stop the [n], leaving the tongue in a [d] position behind the gum ridge; and (b) the tongue has to move down from a [d] position to a [ð] position at the bottom of the incisors. The velic closes fast, and the tongue moves more slowly. It's inevitable, I'm afraid.